# How to access the canvas using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I'm not able to access the canvas id using jquery.

I added the jQuery Library. But I'm not able to get an alert when I click the canvas id.

But javascript is working fine.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sq').click(function(){
    alert('test');
    });
    });
    </script>
    <canvas id="example" width="260" height="200">
        <h2>Shapes</h2>
      <p>A rectangle with a black border. In the background is a pink circle. Partially overlaying the 
      <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle" onfocus="drawCircle();" onblur="drawPicture();">circle</a>. 
      Partially overlaying the circle is a green 
      <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square" onfocus="drawSquare();" onblur="drawPicture();" id="sq">square</a> 
      and a purple <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle" onfocus="drawTriangle();" onblur="drawPicture();">triangle</a>, 
      both of which are semi-opaque, so the full circle can be seen underneath.</p>
    </canvas>​
```

Comment: sorry in jsfiddle canvas tag is not working thing so.Just try to add canvas and give me a example for this - selva

Comment: im trying to make a 3d element in canvas.but its not working in jquery

Comment: Why is your click event inside document ready?

Comment: @RickCalder If it weren't defined in document.ready, the $('#sq') collection would be empty and the event listener wouldn't be registered.

Comment: Thanks, still learning jQuery myself. I assume this is only necessary for elements that don't have their own click event normally?

Comment: `sorry in jsfiddle canvas tag is not working thing` What?? Of course it is working on jsfiddle

Answer (score 3):

Everything you've put inside your `canvas` element is [fallback content](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#embedded-content) : It won't be used in a modern browser so you can't access it and you certainly can't click on it.

The correct use of a `canvas` in a modern browser is to draw onto it using its `context`.

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas) :

> The < canvas > element is an HTML element which can be used to draw
>   graphics via scripting (usually JavaScript). For example, it can be
>   used to draw graphs, make photo compositions, create animations or
>   even do real-time video processing.

If you want to catch clicks on the `canvas`, do

```
$('#example').click(function(){ // <-- use the id of the canvas
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: wait bro ill give a example site for this

Answer (score 1):

You are not suppose to put html elements inside the canvas tag. The idea of the canvas is to **draw** on it using code (a.k.a. javascript).
What you are doing isn't gonna work (or more likely will be seen only if the browser doesn't support canvas - which means very very old browsers) :)

Comment: how can i explain that one.wait bro ill give an example site.

Answer (score 1):

Take the html elements out of the canvas and change `$('#sq').click(function(){` to `$('#example').click(function(){`

Look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zprb4/